# Runtime Exception..cannot create directory in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio...created the environment variable and initially while I was trying to create a new project from the Quick Start page, nothing was happening...then somehow I tried to get to the HelloWorld project and now while trying to create a new project I'm getting error msg

2:50:19 AM RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory 'C:\Users\UserName...
I'm kind of lost..please suggest...

Comment: Sounds like something may be wrong with your installation. Have you tried uninstalling and then reinstalling Android Studio?

Comment: Yes Demitrian...I have uninstalled n reinstalled Android Studio n have tried to rename my CLASS_PATH as well as have Invalidated Caches/Restart

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your project on a mac this is how you install it: 
Go to http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?gclid=CI-Nw4SQ5MoCFQUFwwodfl0HyA, download android studio, mac has java jdk 1.6 preinstalled but you can install java jdk 1.8 from oracle http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html. Run android studio and let android studio do its thing, don't worry about any environment setup you are good to go.

On windows, you will have to install java jdk from same link and add java to path. install and run android studio and you are good to go. You can remove the one you have and reinstall. Hope this help